# How to populate buttons from object dynamically in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to fill the name and value of buttons using the key value pairs of an object.

This is the object:

```
let toppings = {
  pepperoni: 0.25,
  meatballs: 0.35,
  mushrooms: 0.35,
  olives: 0.2,
};
```

These are the buttons:

```
<button class=" add-cart" name="" value="">
<button class=" add-cart" name="" value="">
<button class=" add-cart" name="" value="">
<button class=" add-cart" name="" value="">
```

Is it possible? How would I do that? So far, I could loop through the buttons but I don´t know how to add the values. I´ve tried with a nested loop but It does not work!

```
let addCart = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart');

for (let btn of addCart) {
  btn.name = ?
  btn.value = ?
}
```

Comment: You need to loop through `Object.keys(toppings)` and `addCart` simaltaneously with one loop using an index counter and fill `btn.value` as `toppings[key]` and `btn.innerHTML` as the `key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this block code you can fill buttons value attr and textContent by your mention Object also if buttons length be equal with object length

```js
let toppings = {
  pepperoni: 0.25,
  meatballs: 0.35,
  mushrooms: 0.35,
  olives: 0.2,
};

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const objLength = Object.keys(toppings).length;


if(buttons.length === objLength) {
  Object.keys(toppings).forEach((key,index) => {
    buttons[index].textContent = key    
  })
  
  Object.values(toppings).forEach((val,index) => {
    buttons[index].setAttribute('value', val)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do this is to loop over your keys in the toppings object. While looping take your buttons and use `setAttribute` to set any value you want.

Like this

```
Object.keys(toppings).forEach((name, index) => {
      addCart[index].setAttribute('name', name);
      addCart[index].setAttribute('value', toppings[name]);
      addCart[index].innerHTML = name;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As example, you can iterate your object thru the Object.keys method, and when you access your object's data, you can create your buttons in loop dynamically, set them attributes et.c. here is tiny example based on your question:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
const toppings = {
  pepperoni: 0.25,
  meatballs: 0.35,
  mushrooms: 0.35,
  olives: 0.2,
};

const targetNode = document.getElementById('root')

Object.keys(toppings).forEach((tName) => {
  let button = document.createElement("button")
  button.innerHTML = tName;
  button.setAttribute('name',tName)
  button.setAttribute('value',toppings[tName])
  targetNode.append(button)
})
```

https://codepen.io/zaslavskij/pen/jOBWqwv

Answer (score 1):

```js
let toppings = {
  pepperoni: 0.25,
  meatballs: 0.35,
  mushrooms: 0.35,
  olives: 0.2,
};

const toppingsIterator = Object.entries(toppings).values();
let addCart = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart');

for (let btn of addCart) {
  let [[name, value]] = toppingsIterator;
  btn.name = name;
  btn.value = value;
  btn.textContent = `${name} - ${value}`;
}


//for demo purpose - delegate event listener for the add-cart buttons
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const el = e.target;
  
  if (!el.matches(".add-cart")) return;
  
  console.log(el.name, el.value);
});
```

```html
<button class=" add-cart" name="" value="">
<button class=" add-cart" name="" value="">
<button class=" add-cart" name="" value="">
<button class=" add-cart" name="" value="">
```

1. Take an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterator_protocol) over the toppings by calling [`Array#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) on the result of [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).
2. Iterate over the buttons.
3. Each iteration get the next item from the iterator using [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) because [it works on iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#syntaxes_expecting_iterables)
4. Destructure the item from the iterator into a name and value.